# Why does ReSharper think that "thread.Name == null" is always false?

Tags: c#, multithreading, resharper

I am writing a helper method for conveniently setting the `Name` of a `Thread`:

```
public static bool TrySetName(this Thread thread, string name)
{
    try
    {
        if (thread.Name == null)
        {
            thread.Name = name;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It's working as intended. ReSharper, however, claims that the condition is always false and the corresponding code is heuristically unreachable. That's wrong. A `Thread.Name` is always null until a string is assigned.

[image]

So, why does ReSharper think it is? And is there some way to tell ReSharper it isn't (other than `// ReSharper disable ...`)?

I'm using ReSharper 5.1.3.

Comment: I'm using ReSharper 6 and it doesn't complain.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was fixed in 6+ of RS I think. See [here](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5273899).

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be a bug in R#, fixed in v6.

see: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5366898