# Check if OpenFileDialog.OpenFile is null

Tags: c#, null

I've gone through this code in [the msdn doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.openfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Stream myStream = null;
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
[...] // Some init
try
{
    if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
    {
        using (myStream)
        {
            // Insert code to read the stream here.
        }
    }
}
```

But Resharper gently tell me that checking for null is useless:

[image]

Should I trust Resharper or Microsoft?

Comment: Always trust the developer, Resharper is just a code "hinter"

Comment: @James not this time...

Comment: yes in this case Resharper was correct (FYI I never said it was wrong). However, I stand by what I said, *always* trust the developer over a 3rd party tool. What's to stop the developer changing the behaviour of this method behind the scenes at somepoint? Ultimately, the code you have there is fine, unnecessary, but fine - you might even find the compiler is smart enough to remove it anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R# is right on this one, if you decompile the class (see code below) it's implemented in a way **that can never return null** (it always returns a stream or throws an exception):

```
public Stream OpenFile()
{
    IntSecurity.FileDialogOpenFile.Demand();
    string str = this.FileNamesInternal[0];

    if (str == null || str.Length == 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("FileName");

    new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, IntSecurity.UnsafeGetFullPath(str)).Assert();

    try
    {
        return (Stream) new FileStream(str, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
    }
    finally
    {
        CodeAccessPermission.RevertAssert();
    }
}
```

That said:

- adding a null check won't change performances at all in that particular use case, so you can keep it. As a general rule, checking for null on a result of a function that is not yours before using it is not a bad practice
- just like every software, R# sometimes has bugs (see for example : [Why does ReSharper think that "thread.Name == null" is always false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13199043/why-does-resharper-think-that-thread-name-null-is-always-false)), so don't blindly follow all its advices :)
- MSDN examples are sometimes not well written, or worse, so don't blindly copy/paste all their examples :)

Answer (score 4):

Here's (most of) the source code for [`OpenFile()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/OpenFileDialog.cs,b9fb6d8411201152).

It's possible for the `try` block to throw an exception, and for the method to return a `Stream` that's `null`, so I'd trust the MSDN docs. I'm not sure why ReSharper is making that suggestion.

```
public Stream OpenFile()
{ 
    string filename = FileNamesInternal[0];

    if (filename == null || (filename.Length == 0))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("FileName");

    Stream s = null; 

    new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, IntSecurity.UnsafeGetFullPath(filename)).Assert();
    try
    {
        s = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read); 
    }
    finally 
    { 
        CodeAccessPermission.RevertAssert();
    } 
    return s;
}
```

Comment: @Thomas It's a great resource for sure.

Comment: No.  If there's an exception then there is no return value.  The returned Stream object can never be *null*.

Comment: @Hans Does the code in the `finally` block prevent `return s` from executing and returning `null`?

Comment: @GrantWinney because the exception would exit the method abrubtly

Comment: Ah, duh, there's no `catch` block so it'd just throw the exception. Missed that.